# Why do we have to assign a temporary pointer to an array in a for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm pretty new to C++, and I'm trying to understand why we need to assign a pointer to an array assuming the array size is known like the first part of the loop here.

```
for(int * ptr = arr; ptr < arr + arrSize; ptr++)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could also do `for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)` and work with `myArr[i]`. Or  a range-based `for` loop if the size is known at compile time. Either way you'll need *some* kind of iterator, be it a pointer moving along the array, an `int` that stands for the array index or the iterator that the range based loop sets up under the hood.

Comment: You don't have to do this, there are many ways to iterate over an array. It would help to clarify your question

Comment: "*why we need to assign a pointer*" You don't. You can if you want, but you don't need to.

Answer (score 3):

For starters array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So in this declaration

```
int * ptr = arr
```

there is being created local variable `ptr` that will point to the first element of the array `arr`.

This expression

```
arr + arrSize
```

points to one past the last element of the array `arr`.

So within the loop due to increments of the pointer `ptr`  all elements of the array are sequentially accessed until the pointer `ptr` will point to one past the last element of the array.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t arrSize = 5;
    int arr[arrSize] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( int *ptr = arr; ptr != arr + arrSize; ptr++ )
    {
        std::cout << "ptr = " << ptr << ", &arr[" << i << "] = " << &arr[i] << '\n';
        std::cout << "*ptr = " << *ptr << ", arr[" << i << "] = " << arr[i] << '\n';
        std::cout << '\n';

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
ptr = 0x7ffeb74dbd00, &arr[0] = 0x7ffeb74dbd00
*ptr = 1, arr[0] = 1

ptr = 0x7ffeb74dbd04, &arr[1] = 0x7ffeb74dbd04
*ptr = 2, arr[1] = 2

ptr = 0x7ffeb74dbd08, &arr[2] = 0x7ffeb74dbd08
*ptr = 3, arr[2] = 3

ptr = 0x7ffeb74dbd0c, &arr[3] = 0x7ffeb74dbd0c
*ptr = 4, arr[3] = 4

ptr = 0x7ffeb74dbd10, &arr[4] = 0x7ffeb74dbd10
*ptr = 5, arr[4] = 5
```

Pay attention to that in this expression

```
arr + arrSize
```

there is used the so-called pointer arithmetic. For example

```
( arr + arrSize ) - arr
```

gives the number of elements `arrSize` between the two pointer expressions `arr + arrSize` and `arr`.